# Google Visualization TreeMap fetching color on clicking each segment of the treemap

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization, treemap

Is it possible to get the color of of the segment clicked on the treemap.
On clicking a select event is fired which just gives us which row has been clicked.

[Here is an example](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#tree_map)

Comment: an example fiddle would really help your cause here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found any way of doing this with the Google API, but by adding a `click` event listener to the document and matching it up with the `select` event, you can retrieve the actual `SVGRectElement` value:

```
var currElement;
document.addEventListener('click', function (k) {
    currElement = k.target;
});

google.visualization.events.addListener(treemap, 'select', function () {
  var sel = treemap.getSelection(),
      color;
  if (currElement) {
      color = currElement.attributes.getNamedItem('fill');
  }

  console.log('selected element color: ' + color.value);
});
```

This is by no means a complete solution, but it should point you to an answer

Comment: I think since both of them are triggered by click, at the first click the color is not set by the time its the chart listener. Any suggestions on that ? thanks for the answer